# POST API stopped working in iOS Swift after changing base URL of Rest APIs

Tags: ios, swift, server, http-post, nsurlrequest

I am getting bit complex issue. I have integrated REST APIs in my existing iOS Swift based Application. It works all correctly.

Now we just changed our domain server so the Base URL of the REST APIs shifted & changed. Now what the issue I am getting is after changing the BaseURL my all POST APIs stopped working.

**Note :**

- I did checked in POSTMan it works correctly
- I did tested on Android it works correctly
- Even GET APIs with changed BaseURL works correctly on iOS
- Only POST APIs not working after changing baseURL

Here is the error message I am getting :

```
statusCode should be 200, but is 500
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x282dfd960> { URL: API_BASE_URL/check_social_id } { Status Code: 500, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        289
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 02 Sep 2019 09:41:13 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
} })
```

Note that there is no issue with the API code as its still works with the old BaseURL. Everything with the same code if I just change it to the old BaseURL it works correctly. But If I use new URL it gives the error as I stated above.

**New Edit :**
After some suggestions I have tried to use the Alamofire library & now I am getting some different error message. Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let urlString = "API_URL"
        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["media_type": "gmail", "media_id":"12121212121", "fname":"mSolu", "email":"demo.test@gmail.com"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New error message :

```
responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}))
```

Any suggestions or hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Status code 500 means Internal Server Error. Are you sure it's not caused by backend? Is your backend using HTTPS?

Comment: I strongly suggest to use HTTPS. But do you allow arbitrary loads in your info.plist?

Comment: I just found that old server was using https & new server is HTTP only

Comment: And do you allow arbitrary loads for all requests or for a specific domain? Maybe that's a reason??? But in that cause you would get different error, not 500

Comment: No idea on it but needs to get the solution for it

Comment: Maybe a different param is needed on new URL. Or it was optional before... Are your using URLSession, or third party lib for the requests? For instance, the param inside the body need to be URL encoded ? JSON encoded ? etc. Maybe check with POSTMAN that can generate code (curl, swift/objective-c, and spot a diff?)

Comment: As others have mentioned, do not use http on its own unless absolutely necessary. Its fine for testing, but deploying an app to production with arbitrary loads is the worst of worst practises. As for other issues, the response constent header mentions `charset=iso-8859-1` typically rest APIs use `application/json` check your POST api's have the content-type set correctly

Comment: @Larme everything is same as old one. Using NSMutableURLRequest

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin let me update my code as well

Comment: @Mayur did you google the error message you are receiving? again it says the response thats coming back is not valid JSON. Print out what is being returned to the console as a string, there is probably information in the content that will tell you the problem

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin tried everything. It all works fine if I change back to old URL. Which has same response I compared & checked in POSTMAN

Comment: both  base urls are using same servers? with same configurations? as 500 means internal server error, and different server can behave diffirently ... so ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan no old was using AWS & current is dedicated server & have some SSL certificate issue. Will API get effected due to this reason ?

Comment: yes SSL certificate will not allow you to post if your resquest dont contains a trust ...

Comment: But strangely it works fine on Android & also works fine on POSTMAN. Only not works on iOS

Comment: i am using ssl certificates  and if certificate is expired or  have invalid trust result it will not allow me to post ...

Comment: anyhow issue is on your server side sometimes server have limited bytes range to accept you need to increase that size and i hope you will be going fine

Comment: @AbuUlHassan ok great let me check by that way

Comment: yeah sure ... take your time ask backend engineer or your devOps to increase request accepting byte size.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan great thanks to all